# delete entity error in type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi guys im facing an error when i try to delete entity

error :

> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception
>   handling request to /updateUseranswers/11:
>   org.lightadmin.core.view.exceptions.BadRequestException:
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [4] did not match
>   expected type [ .entities.useranswers.UserAnswer (n/a)]

service :

```
for (UserAnswerField prevUserAnswerField : userAnswerFieldRepo.getUserAnswerFields(userAnswer.getAnswerId())) {
    userAnswerFieldRepo.deleteUserAnswerField(prevUserAnswerField.getfieldId().intValue());     
}
```

repo :

```
public void deleteUserAnswerField(Integer answerId) {
    Query delQuery = getEntityManagerFactory().createQuery("delete from UserAnswerField sff where sff.userAnswerId=:answerId");
    delQuery.setParameter("answerId", answerId);
    delQuery.executeUpdate();
}
```

UserAnswer entity :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "answer_id")
private Integer answerId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "user_id")

private int userId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 500)
@Column(name = "label")
private String label;
@Basic(optional = true)
@Column(name = "insertion_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date insertionDate;
@Column(name = "is_active")
private Boolean isActive;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
@Column(name = "type")
private String type;

@Transient
private List<UserAnswerField> answerFields;
```

UserAnswerField entity :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "field_id")
private Integer fieldId;
@JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private UserAnswerType typeId;
@JoinColumn(name = "answer_id", referencedColumnName = "answer_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private UserAnswer userAnswerId;
@Size(max = 500)
@Column(name = "field")
private String field;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `where sff.userAnswerId.answerId = :answerId`.

`userAnswerId` in `UserAnswerField` is of type `UserAnswer`; just navigate to its id.

Comment: Thanks Dragan ! I missed that